# boost managed shared memory segfault

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

I am trying to create a program where various processes can access data stored in the managed shared memory. I am utilizing boost to accomplish the task. I have three files, shared_memory.h, shared_memory.cc, and main.cc.

`shared_memory.h`

```
#ifndef __SHARED_ITN__
#define __SHARED_ITN__

#include <fst/fstlib.h>

#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>


enum TokenType { SYMBOL = 1, BYTE = 2, UTF8 = 3 };  
using namespace boost::interprocess;

typedef fst::VectorFst<fst::StdArc> Transducer;
typedef allocator<Transducer, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> shmMyFstAllocator;
typedef boost::interprocess::vector<Transducer, shmMyFstAllocator> shmMyFst;

class SharedItn {

    public:
        SharedItn();
        SharedItn(std::vector<string> model_path);
        bool Read(std::vector<string> model_path, string input_str, string &output_str);
        void Remove();
        virtual ~SharedItn();

    private:
        static const string SHM_OBJ_IDENTIFIER;
        static const int SHM_OBJ_SIZE;
        shmMyFst* myFstPtr;
};

#endif
```

The corresponding c++ code, shared_memory.cc is:

`shared_memory.cc`

```
#include "shared_memory.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

using namespace fst;

typedef VectorFst<StdArc> Transducer;
typedef StringCompiler<StdArc> Compiler;

const string SharedItn::SHM_OBJ_IDENTIFIER = "SHARED_ITN_MODULES";
const int SharedItn::SHM_OBJ_SIZE = 104857600;

SharedItn::SharedItn() {
}

SharedItn::SharedItn(std::vector<string> model_path) {  
try {
    // Create managed shared memory object
    shared_memory_object::remove(SHM_OBJ_IDENTIFIER.c_str());
    managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, SHM_OBJ_IDENTIFIER.c_str(), SHM_OBJ_SIZE);

    // Construct fst model within the shared memory object
    shmMyFstAllocator alloc_inst(segment.get_segment_manager());
    myFstPtr = segment.construct<shmMyFst>(model_path[0].c_str())(alloc_inst);

    // Insert the loaded fst model into shared memory
    Transducer* tmp_model_fst = Transducer::Read(model_path[0]);            
    myFstPtr->push_back(*tmp_model_fst);

} catch (interprocess_exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
}

SharedItn::~SharedItn() {}

bool SharedItn::Read(std::vector<string> model_path, string input_str, string& output_str) {

Transducer* transTmp;
shmMyFst* tmp;

try {
    managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, SHM_OBJ_IDENTIFIER.c_str());
    tmp = segment.find<shmMyFst>(model_path[0].c_str()).first;
    for(int i = 0; i < tmp->size(); i++)
        transTmp = tmp->at(i).Copy(true);

} catch (interprocess_exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        return false;
}

return true;
}

void SharedItn::Remove() {
try {
    shared_memory_object::remove(SHM_OBJ_IDENTIFIER.c_str());
} catch(interprocess_exception& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
}
```

And finally the main.cc file where server/client process is created.

`main.cc`

```
#include "shared_memory.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

if(argc != 2) {
    std::cout << "Must provide either 'server' or 'client' as input." << std::endl;
    return -1;
} else {
        std::vector<string> file_path;
        std::string file = "rule_PRE_PROC.fst";
        file_path.push_back(file);

        string input_str = "";
        string result_str;

        if(std::string(argv[1]) == "server") {
            SharedItn loader(file_path);

            while(1)    {
                std::cout << "Input test string: " << std::endl;
                getline(std::cin, input_str);
                if(input_str.compare("quit") == 0) {
                    loader.Remove();
                    std::cout << "Terminating." << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
                loader.Read(file_path, input_str, result_str);
                std::cout << "RESULT: " << result_str << std::endl;
            }
        } else if(std::string(argv[1]) == "client") {
                SharedItn loader;

                while(1)    {
                    std::cout << "Input test string: " << std::endl;
                    getline(std::cin, input_str);
                    if(input_str.compare("quit") == 0) {
                        loader.Remove();
                        std::cout << "Terminating." << std::endl;
                        break;
                    }
                    loader.Read(file_path, input_str, result_str);
                    std::cout << "RESULT: " << result_str << std::endl;
                }
        }
}   
}
```

When I run the program as the server mode, everything works fine. However, when I have a running server process and create an additional client process, it segfaults when trying to find the constructed object within the shared memory. More specifically, the segfault occurs in the following code: `transTmp = tmp->at(i).Copy(true);` within the `SharedItn::Read` function.

My best guess is that the find method called by the client isn't functioning correctly. However, I can't figure out what the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As you see nobody was willing to dig through this mass of code. Try it the next time with an MCVE.

Comment: @AlBundy 7 hours is very short for low-traffic tags. The code is what is known as SSCCE

Answer (score 1):

Unless `Transducer` is POD, this is likely your problem.

If `fst::Vector<>` allocates outside the shared memory segment, it will address out of bounds in a differen process.

Comment: A quick google search turned up this [link](http://www.openfst.org/doxygen/fst/html/vector-fst_8h_source.html) for `VectorFst`. Assuming this is the library the OP is using, it is most definitely **not** a POD type.

Comment: @NathanErnst agreed. I had it installed. Lost interest when i saw a number of other elementary code issues. Decided to just point out the essential problem

Comment: you already got my upvote. The issue you pointed out is definitely an issue (may not be the only one). Non-PODs containing pointers to dynamically allocated memory will most definitely not play well with shared memory.